# Non-group key variable in SELECT

Tags: sparql, jena

I'm performing with success the following query on virtuoso web interface (e.g.: http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql)

```
SELECT ?o (COUNT(?member) as ?memberCount) WHERE {
  ?member <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> ?o.
  FILTER isIRI(?o) {
    SELECT ?o WHERE {
      <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Heroic_Purgatory>
      <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject>
      ?o.
    }
  }
}
ORDER BY ?memberCount
LIMIT 1
```

When I do this query through Apache Jena, an exception rises up:

```
Non-group key variable in SELECT: ?o
```

I don't understand why... any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `GROUP BY ?o` before `ORDER BY`, solved my issue.

Comment: try to add group by ?o before ORDER BY ?memberCount, you will see that it works fine

Answer (score 0):

That still be illegal (and is current Apache Jena).

`SELECT` can only have `GROUP BY` variables and aggregations.

When there is no `GROUP BY` but is an aggregation, `COUNT` here, then it an implicit `GROUP BY` on the whole of the results (no `GROUP BY` key) so no variable directly mentioned, only aggregates, are possible.